# SyntaxNode.ContainsDiagnostics not working with your own diagnostics?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, static-code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to write an analyzer that prevents users from providing parameters that are automatically provided (ex: by the compiler with `[CallerMemberName]`) and I want the analyzer to error you when you have provided a parameter that shouldn't be provided (to tell a parameter shouldn't be provided I created an attribute : `DontProvideAttribute`).

The thing is such automatically provided parameters must be optional (otherwise the value provided by the user would be written over the one provided automatically) so I've made a second analyze to prevent users from using `[DontProvide]` on non-optional parameters.

And there comes the problem, I want the error on the method invocation to be there only if the parameter declaration doesn't have the `[DontProvide] should only be used on optional parameters` error which

```
foreach (SyntaxReference parameterDefinition in parameter.DeclaringSyntaxReferences)
{
    if (parameterDefinition.GetSyntax().ContainsDiagnostics)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

should complete this but it seems like it doesn't consider diagnostics you reported yourself.

**What i have tried :**

-Changing the order of diagnostics to make the declaration being analyzed before the method invocation

-Use `.GetDiagnostics().Count() > 0` instead

-Changing the order of the text in the analyzed document to have the method declaration above the method invocation

**The analyzer :**

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeParametersDeclaration, SymbolKind.Parameter);
    context.RegisterOperationAction(AnalyzeArguments, OperationKind.Argument);
}

private void AnalyzeArguments(OperationAnalysisContext context)
{
    IArgumentOperation reference = (IArgumentOperation)context.Operation;
    IParameterSymbol parameter = reference.Parameter;
    foreach (SyntaxReference parameterDefinition in parameter.DeclaringSyntaxReferences)
    {
        if (parameterDefinition.GetSyntax().ContainsDiagnostics)
            return;
    }
    foreach (AttributeData attribute in parameter.GetAttributes())
    {
        if (attribute.AttributeClass.Name == "DontProvideAttribute")
        {
            context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(DontProvide, reference.Syntax.GetLocation(), parameter.Name));
        }
    }
}

private void AnalyzeParametersDeclaration(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
    IParameterSymbol parameter = (IParameterSymbol)context.Symbol;
    if (parameter.GetAttributes().Any(a => a.AttributeClass.Name == "DontProvideAttribute") && !parameter.IsOptional)
    {
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(DontProvideOnlyForOptional, parameter.Locations[0]))         
    }
}
```

**Some test code for analyze :**

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass.MyMethod(null);
        }
    }

    internal class MyClass
    {
        public static void MyMethod([DontProvide] object parameter)
        {

        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
    public class DontProvideAttribute : Attribute
    {

    } 
}
```

**PS** : The compiler may tell you that `context.RegisterSymbolAction()` used with `SymbolKind.Parameter` isn't supported, which is wrong ([see more here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16214))

Comment: "it seems like it doesn't consider diagnostics you reported yourself." That is correct indeed. Now what is your question?

Comment: Well my question basically was "is what i think true?" And now that you answered it well I'm looking for a workaround to still be able to detect if the parameter declaration has a diagnostic or not ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion [here](https://gitter.im/dotnet/roslyn) and @Kris Vandermotten's comment

> ContainsDiagnostics is only for syntactic diagnostics (i.e. diagnostics acutally inside the syntax tree)
>   not for diagnostics reported by later passes (i.e. semantic diagnostics or your own analyzer diagnostics).
>   Here's why : a specific syntax tree may be contained in many different semantic contexts due to roslyn being able to fork and speculate about things
>   so in one context, the syntax may be semantically correct, and in another, it won't be
>   as such, the diagnostics are not stored on the tree itself.

In fact the solution in my case was pretty simple : i just had to remove

```
foreach (SyntaxReference parameterDefinition in parameter.DeclaringSyntaxReferences)
{
    if (parameterDefinition.GetSyntax().ContainsDiagnostics)
        return;
}
```

and add `&& parameter.IsOptionnal` on the `if` statement there :

```
foreach (AttributeData attribute in parameter.GetAttributes())
{
    if (attribute.AttributeClass.Name == "DontProvideAttribute")
    {
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(DontProvide, reference.Syntax.GetLocation(), parameter.Name));
    }
}
```